# How to merge Arrays in RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, sparkcore, bigdata

I'm newbie in Spark. I have the following RDD[Array[(String, String, String)]]

```
val r1 = sc.parallelize(Array(Array(("123","456","789"),("AAA","BBB","CCC")),Array(("DDD","EEE","FFF"),("E1","E2","E3"))))
```

I want to merge Arrays in it like

```
Array((123,456,789), (AAA,BBB,CCC), (DDD,EEE,FFF), (E1,E2,E3))
```

I can do this with `r1.reduce(_ ++ _)`. However, I want to use Transformations functions like map, not Actions ones. Is it possible to do that? I'm using Spark 1.3.1.

Thank you

Comment: `flatMap` is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
val res: RDD[(String, String, String)] = r1.flatMap(identity)
```